# FileOutputStream closing before all data is written to file?

Tags: java, android, xml, fileoutputstream

I'm developing an Android application, using `FileOutputStream` to write data to file in the XML format, using the code below.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

fos.write(getXMLFileHeader().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
fos.write(getXMLProject().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
fos.write(getXMLReportData().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
fos.write(getXMLFileFooter().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

The file is being created and some of the data written...but not all of it. I'm expecting to see something like the following in the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Project name="Report1" creator="Pete">
    <Report>This would be where the data for the report would go.</Report>
</Project>
```

However, what I am seeing is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Project name="Report1" creator="Pete">
    <Report>This would be where the data for the
```

As you can see, it seems to stop writing to the file before it's closed. Could anyone tell me how to fix this? Thanks!

**Edit:** Added example of `getXML*()` method.

```
private String getXMLReportData() {

    return "<Report>" + GlobalVariables.strReportData + "</Report>";
}
```

These methods simply return a string like in the example above.

Comment: Are you sure the output stream or the file is not shared between more than one thread ? Or maybe an exception is thrown before flush() occurs ?

Comment: @Abhishek Thank you, I've amended my code to write it all in one go and that seems to have worked. However I'm doing what I did in another application, writing several times one after the other and don't have any problems...not sure why it works in one application and not in this one!

Comment: `once you do write operation your stream is closed`. @Abhishek Sorry but that is nonsense.

Comment: @greenapps I was suspicious that was not correct, it may be coincidence my application is now working as it should...

Comment: the problem may also be in the `getXML*()` methods

Comment: @nandsito I've added an example of this

Comment: it is still not conclusive... the issue may be manifest storage permission, the file path, some exception not being handled, etc.